# Do not fire 'zoom_changed' event when fitbounds() is in used

Tags: google-maps, zooming, fitbounds

In my init i have some thing like this

```
google.maps.event.addListener(gmap, 'zoom_changed', function(){
    GMapPlot.getSwNe(window.gmap.getBounds());
    //GMapPlot.rePlotMap(presentPlaceType);
});
```

and at some point i have `gmap.fitBounds(GMapPlot.markerBounds);`, my question is `fitBounds` fires a `zoom_changed` event that intern invokes the bound method, i don't want this to happen, is there a way to do that. If i try to `clearListener` for `zoom_changed` event before that `fitBounds` is not working.